# How to get the next version from packaging.version?

Tags: python, version, packaging

I have the following

```
from packaging import version
current_ver = version.parse(ver_string)
```

this gives me a `Version` object containing something like `0.0.0.9`.

Now I want the next version, meaning `0.0.0.10`.

How do I get it?

I tried

```
next_ver = current_ver + 1
next_ver = next(current_ver)
```

which appears to be the wrong usage.

Didn't find anything useful in [the doc](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/latest/version/#packaging.version.parse)

I don't want to parse it myself, I'm sure someone else did it better before me.

Comment: Versioning is not just add a number on the last digit, should refer to [Semantic Version](https://semver.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install version-parser`.

Refer to [this](https://pypi.org/project/version-parser/), you can get the digit wanted by `get_build_version()`